# Client area turns into black when minimize window

Tags: c++, mfc

I used MFC to create an application like Paint. My program have a problem that when I minimize it and maximize again, all client area turn into black and every shape or picture on client area are erased. I don't know why and how to handle this error (I draw every thing in OnPaint() funtion). I need some help. Thank everyone !
Edited: A part of my OnPaint():

```
else if(state == 2 && openPen == 1)
{
    CClientDC dc(this);
    CRgn ellipse;
    ellipse.CreateEllipticRgn(pPen.x, pPen.y, pPen.x + 5, pPen.y + 5);
    myBrush.CreateStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    CBrush* oldBrush =  (CBrush*)dc.SelectObject(&myBrush);
    dc.FillRgn(&ellipse, &myBrush);
    dc.SelectObject(oldBrush);
    myBrush.DeleteObject();
}
```

state and openPen is flags, they show that user choose "Pen" option.

Comment: Show some code. What happens if you drag the window out of the screen and then back into screen ? Is the windows repainted then properly or not ?

Comment: I am new in MFC. I only use some functions such as: Fill, Rectangle... When I minimize window, "state" and "openPen" flags is still 2 and 1, so why does the client area turn into black? Can you help me please? Thank you very much.

Comment: Answer my question:  What happens if you drag the window out of the screen and then back into screen ? Is the windows repainted then properly or not ?

Comment: Michael, If I drag the window out of the screen then back, the client turns into dark and some buttons is not in their old position.

Answer (score 0):

The OnPaint function must use CPaintDC, not CClientDC. The CPaintDC constructor and destructor perform the necessary validation of the invalid region.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I changed CClientDC to CPaintDC but the problem still exists.

Comment: @PhùngKhánhHiên post your OnPaint function.

Comment: Sorry Michael Walz, I have been offline for a long time. 
All of my function here:
[MainFrame.cpp](http://pastebin.com/jkV7SCwa)